# Downloading the Repo Client and local Mirror | Android Open Source Project

Tags: project, tee, repo

I'm following this [guide](https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading) to download the Repo for client, mirror and master.
My doubt concerns that when i run:

```
repo sync
```

download me:

- For repo client: ~ 150GB
- For repo mirror: more than 320GB (I don't know how match, because I have no more memory space)
- For repo master: I don't know but the web page says that is similar to repo mirror

So, my question is: is this huge amount of data being downloaded normal? I would like to understand this since my pc only has 500GB.